# Normal force not perpendicular?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

[image]

Why does the normal force act upward at the point of contact? Isn't the normal force always perpendicular to the point of contact?

(This is from 2014 F=MA exam)

Comment: Perpendicular to the surface, yes. Which in the case of the ground is straight up.

Comment: Drawing a diagram with these things (almost) always helps if you're stuck

Comment: the tilt is because rider leans at an angle to balance the torque, bigger angle the rider go off the turn and smaller angle is hurtful.

Answer (score 3):

If a body is being supported by a surface, the normal force acting on the body is always perpendicular to the surface, irrespective of the tilt of the body.

It is not specifically stated in the question whether or not the track is flat or banked, so you could not know based upon the parameters of the question what angle the normal force would be acting at. However, given that the solution tells you that the normal force is acting upwards, we can deduce that the reason it is doing so is that the surface of the track is flat, and not banked.

Comment: So if I cannot see the solution, would I just have to assume some things? Like if the track is banked or not?

Comment: Why is always perpendicular?

Comment: @adosar The normal force is always perpendicular to the face of the body that is being pushed against, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

The cyclists interacts with the ground at the point of contact between the tyre(s) and the ground.

The ground exerts a force $\vec F$ on the cyclist as shown in the left hand diagram.

[image]

To solve some problems it is useful to resolve the force $\vec F$ into two components as shown in the right hand diagram.

The two forces are a frictional force $\vec F_{\rm f}$ which acts along the surface and a normal force $\vec F_{\rm n}$ which acts at right angles to the surface.
The forve $\vec F_{\rm n}$ is called the normal force.

> Why does the normal force act upward at the point of contact?

By definition the normal force acts at right angles to a surface and if the ground is horizontal then the normal force will act upwards in this example.

To ensure that there is no torque about the centre of mass of the cyclist the line of action of the force $\vec F$ must pass through the centre of mass and using this condition will produce the equation which you have stated for $\theta$.